# How to set comments manully for Class, Method and Field in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

There is a checkbox `Enable Live Template` here, but how to use `Class Header` in Live Template.

[image]

Who knows the best way to set comments manully for Class, Method and Field in Intellij Idea like the Code Template in Eclipse ??

Answer (score 0):

`File Header.java` and `Class Header.java` corresponds to templates on the neighbour `includes` tab:
[image: File Header.java location]

Not sure for what you meant for

> set comments manully for Class, Method and Field in Intellij Idea like
>   the Code Template in Eclipse

In Intellij IDEA you can position cursor above declaraion of class/field/method and press `/** Enter`. This will generate javadoc, for example, for method: `@param`, `@return`, `@throws`, etc. 
Great instructions on creating new templates are, for example, here: [How configure Intellij Idea javadoc templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607925/how-configure-intellij-idea-javadoc-templates/38094408)